# max in reverse polish notation (RPN)

Tags: computer-science, polish-notation

I am trying to implement max in my infixToPostfix generator. I did not ask this question on stackoverflow because it is more of a mathematical thing. I hope this is the right place.

$(1+2) / max(1,2,(3+4)/2)$ returns `1 2 + 1 2 3 4 + 2 / max /`. This is right ouptput except I don't know how to solve the returned `RPN`. I mean RPN takes indefinite arguments. I thought of adding a suffix to max when converting from infix to postfix which indicates the number of arguments. I also thought of adding something like `&` or `@` to tell that till here are the arguments. But I am looking for something universal. Are there any defined rules for RPN? If yes please provide with the answer the link to rules. I am also having problems implementing the unary $-$(negative). So if I could read the rules and implement it.

Comment: As you've asked it, it does not seem like a mathematics question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule for calculating an expression in RPN is:

- Make a stack of numbers
- Process your RPN expression left-to-right
- When you see a number, push it to the top of the stack
- When you see a binary operator (e.g. +), apply that operator to the top-most two entries on the stack, pop those two entries and push the result.
- When you see a unary operator, apply it to the top-most entry on the stack, pop that entry and push the result.
- In general, if you see an $n$-ary operator, apply it to the top $n$ entries on the stack, pop those $n$ entries and push the result.

In the end, there will be only one number on the stack - the result.

As for unary minus, treat it as a unary operator, e.g.:

$$-(2-3)+5\to 23-_{binary}-_{unary}5+$$

As you see, you need to distinguish the binary minus from the unary minus.

Comment: But question asks how to implement `max` function in rpn form. The max function takes indefinite number of arguments so how entries to pop from the stack?

Comment: You don’t. You must treat $\max$ functions with different number of arguments as different operators. They are different functions mathematically, anyways. So in your example the operator would be something like $max_3$